# How to expand math field in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, latex, mathjax, tex

Math formula field is small.

This is default behavior of the Latex plugin. Can the field can be expanded? If yes, then how can I do that?

I have browse to fix this solution but none of them match with what I want. Anyone know how to expand it?

This is the screen shot:

[image]

**UPDATED**

```
return{title:b.title,minWidth:1000,minHeight:650,contents:[{id:"info",elements:[{id:"equation",type:"textarea",rows:10,label:b.dialogInput, ..
```

[image]

Note: I can expand the dialog display but I cannot expand the textfield formula form. It seem like the variable `rows` not functioning.

Should I declare the variable `rows` in other file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the code that displays this dialog.

In your `ckeditor` folder, under the `/plugins/mathjax/dialogs/` folder, open the `mathjax.js` file.

To make the dialog wider change the `minWidth` attributes. For example, to set the width to 750 pixels:

```
return {
    title: lang.title,
    minWidth: 750,
    minHeight: 100,
    contents: [
```

To add more lines to the formula textbox, add the `rows` attribute with the number of lines you want (the `rows` attribute is not there by default so add it). For example, to make the textbox 10 lines long:

```
elements: [
    {
        id: 'equation',
        type: 'textarea',
        rows: 10,
        label: lang.dialogInput,
```

Here's a screenshot with the above changes:

[image: Example]

Save the file and clear your cache before testing.

Comment: Hi @Atzmon . Sorry for late reply.. I have try to put this code `rows: 10` between attribute type and label. Once I refresh the page and try to click the icon math, the pop up of the formula textbox does not show. 

Do I need to set the variable rows in other file?

Comment: Hi its my mistake. Because of the habit of copy and paste, the codes have double " , " coma. I am sorry. After I remove one of the " , " the formula textbox appear but the textfield remain same. The textfield still use the default size

Comment: I tested this with a vanilla varsion of ckeditor and the mathjax plugin. I suggest you [download a fresh copy](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax) of the mathjax plugin and carefully apply the changes again.

Comment: Hi @Atzmon so by default we just put the attribute `rows` inside the elements? No need to declare `rows` in other file? I just want to make it sure

Comment: Yes, see the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.textarea-property-rows) for `textarea` and its `rows` attribute.

Comment: Ok.  I think your answer is accepted and the problem is  maybe came from my codes. Maybe there is setting need to be change and also need to discuss with my team 

thank you. (Y)

Comment: Hi @Atzmon I have open link that you provide at above `download a fresh copy` and on step 2 I need to put extra plugin `config.extraPlugins = 'mathjax';` . Where should I put this plugin?

Comment: In the page that hosts ckeditor, assuming your textarea is called `editor1`, you probably have a javascript call to `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );`. This function accepts a list of extra plugins like this: `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {extraPlugins: 'mathjax'});`.

Comment: Hi @Atzmon.  Thank you for your response :)